# What is the URL to set the admin theme?

Tags: 7, uri

The URL to change the admin theme isn't the same in Drupal 7 compared to 6.  What is the new URL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its at the bottom of the 'Appearance' page (admin/appearance), in the section labeled 'Administration Theme'.